# laravel eloquent - match data stored within array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a multiselect form to store multiple `client_id` in `contact` table:

```
 {!! Form::select('client_id[]', $clients, null, ['multiple'=>true]) !!}
```

When I show an individual client, I wish to show the related contacts.

My `client` Model has as a 1:many relationship defined as:

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\contact');
}
```

usually, for non array items, I would use:

```
$contacts = $client->contact()->get();
```

to fetch related contacts, but as the `client_id` is stored as an array in my `contact` table, how to I fetch this data?

Answer (score 1):

I really think you just want this:

```
$contacts = $client->contact()->lists('id', 'name')->toArray();
```

Note that you didn't specify your version of Laravel, but in `5.1+` lists returns a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance, but in previous versions it returns an `Array`.

**Sidenote**

Your `hasMany` relationship should be defined as plural and not singular:

```
public function contacts()
```

This is by no means a requisite, but it better defines your relationship type.

Comment: This is not working. It doesn't match the client_id of `2` within an array of `"2","3"`